# Combing two integers into 1?

Tags: c, integer

I'm a beginner using C.  I want to combine two integers into 1.  See example code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age[4];
    int mouse[4];
    mouse[0]=50;
    age[0]=23;

    age[1]=mouse[0]age[0];

    printf("%d",age[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have 50 in mouse[0], 23 in age[0], and i want age[1] to be 5023.

What is the simplest way to do this?  This will be a small part of a large code so I really want to keep it simple.  And excuse the silly variable names!

Thanks all!

Comment: If you search for the very expression "combining two integers into one", you will get tens of hits.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth (or google)

Comment: Candidate for worst question title ever..."combining integers"...

Comment: You may want to use a string instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatenate integers like that: you need to do it through some elementary math.

Think of "combining" as multiplication followed by addition:

```
age[1] = mouse[0]*100 + age[0];
```

Here is how it works:

```
A = 23
B = 50, B*100 = 5000

    23
+ 5000
------
  5023
```

Note that this trick works only when the second number has exactly two digits. When the second number has `N` digits, you need to multiply the first number by the `N`-th power of ten before performing the addition.

Comment: Silly arithmetic error: you have an extra zero

Answer (score 0):

`age[1] = 1000*mouse[0] + age[0]`

If you want a more general solution, one that doesn't depend on `mouse[0]` being two digits, you could define a function to get the number of digits:

```
int digits(int num) {
    return ceil(log10(num));
}
```

Then you could combine the integers like so:

```
age[1] = ((int)pow(10, digits(mouse[0])))*mouse[0] + age[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `age[1]=mouse[0]age[0];` to be `age[1]=mouse[0]+age[0];`
If you can always be sure of the magnitude of the two numbers (e.g. two digits) then just multiply by 100 to shift the digits over `age[1]=mouse[0] * 100 + age[0];`

If you don't know the exact digits, then you can calculate how much you have to shift the value over by using log10:

`age[1] = mouse[0] * (int)pow(10, (int)log10(age[0])) + age[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Since OP is doing a string concatenation, covert to text, concatenate and then back to `int`.

```
char buf1[64+64];
char buf2[64];
sprintf(buf1, "%d", mouse[0]);
sprintf(buf2, "%d", age[0]);
strcat(buf1, buf2);
age[1] = atoi(buf1);
```

There are a number of ways to convert `int` into text, `sprintf()` is simple one handy one.  Also a number of wasy to convert text to an `int`.  You have to watch out for the `-` sign and buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are interested in concatenating the textual representation of two ints.

```
int mouse = 50;
int age = 23;

char combi[BUFSIZ];/*char array to contain the "combination"*/

/*print two ints together in one c-string*/
snprintf(combi, BUFSIZ, "%d%d", mouse,age);
printf("value = %s\n", combi); /*print as string*/
```

This would print `value = 5023` to your terminal, in some interpreted languages one might concatenate strings more easily and the textual and numerical representation are converted automagically, however in C this needs to be done very carefully.